# How to delete a folder by parameter and protect by user bugs/errors

Tags: bash, shell, rm

Let's say I have in script something as following which get script input and delete that folder:

```
cd ` dirname "$0" `
X="${1}"
rm -rf ${X}/*
```

I see few bugs in this code:

1. if the user sends `/` or something invalid - a `rm -rf /` will be executed.
2. user can send `..`, `../..` and basically he can travel the folders.

A user is a developer in the company that uses this script, I'm not talking about hackers, client side requests etc. So mostly I'm talking about developer mistakes and lack of knowledge with what they are doing with this script.

I want to prevent `rm -rf /` scenario and anything delete which is not to a folder from the script location downwards.

How should I fix it?

I was thinking on something like:

```
cd ` dirname "$0" `
X="${1}"
rm -rf ./${X}/*
```

But even that is not closing the bug of`..`, and `../..`. I'm sure there is an elegant solution.

Comment: To avoid any additional surprises, I recommend replacing `${X}/*` with `"${X}"/*`.

Comment: You need to define your threat model. What does the potential attacker control? For example, can they control the current working directory (e.g. by running `cd /` before running the script)? What exactly do you need to prevent?

Comment: If you _really_ want to sandbox the process, you get into things like setting up an alternate filesystem namespace with a custom mount table that makes only the specific things you want to be writable writable-in-fact. It's a rabbit hole, and not something narrowly scoped enough to be a good SO question.

Comment: For a lot of purposes, just disallowing `/`s and leading `.`s (along with the forced-relative-path thing you're already doing) suffices. But as someone who does security professionally, under no circumstances am I putting my name next to an answer saying that that's _always_ sufficient when I don't know the details of your use case, threat model, environment, etc. The question is really too broad to be answered.

Comment: BTW, always use `$(...)` instead of backticks. Backticks open you up to bizarre issues where backslashes (and other backticks) are interpreted differently inside vs outside them, so code you tested to work right can suddenly be wrong when you put it inside a command substitution if you're using backtick syntax. `$( )` is POSIX-standardized since the early 1990s, and it's generally a much saner syntax.

Comment: BTW, is it really intentional that you take only `$1` and ignoring `$2` and onward? (For example, making `yourscript *.txt` take only the first .txt file and ignore the others)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only trying to avoid accidental mistakes, then one can keep it pretty simple. Assuming you have GNU `readlink` on your system:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
die() { echo "ERROR: $*" >&2; exit 1; }

source_file=$(readlink -m -- "${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}")
source_dir=${source_file%/*}
dest_file=$(readlink -m -- "$1")

[[ -e "$dest_file" ]] || die "Received argument '$dest_file', which does not exist"
[[ $dest_file = "$source_dir"/* ]] || die "File must be under $source_dir"

rm -rf -- "$dest_file"
```

Because `readlink -m` tries to find the real, absolute path, it'll handle things like `..` walking up the tree.

Comment: `readlink` is cool and simple solution. But it handles `..` as you said :(

Comment: @Nir, the way `readlink -m` handles `..` is _why_ this code solves your problem. `readlink -m` will change `/opt/yourscript/bin/../../../etc` to `/etc`, which means that `[[ $dest_file = "$source_dir"/* ]]` will fail if `source_dir` is `/opt/yourscript`.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! what is the `--` in `$(readlink -m -- "$1")` and in `rm -rf -- "$dest_file"`?

Comment: found the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Answer (score 0):

Shell is not a security focused language. At best you can anticipate the most obvious risky user error and it is what I propose you with checking the user entered path is within the allowed base directory.

At least, it prevents some of the most dramatic user errors.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

user_entry="$1"

# Define the allowed base directory
allowed_base_dir="$PWD"

# Collect the real path of the user entered directory
real_entered_dir="$(
  cd "$user_entry" 2>/dev/null && echo "$PWD"
)"

# Check the real user provided path starts with the allowed path
case $real_entered_dir in
  "$allowed_base_dir"*)
    echo 'ok'
    echo rm -rf -- "$real_entered_dir"
    ;;
  *)
    printf 'User entered path "%s" expanding to "%s", which is not within the allowd "%s"\n' \
    "$user_entry" "$real_entered_dir" "$allowed_base_dir" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: There's a fair bit of performance hit in using `$(pwd)` instead of `$PWD`. Is there a payoff / benefit / purpose?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought `$PWD` was a bashism.

Comment: It's POSIX; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html. *Set by the shell and by the cd utility. In the shell the value shall be initialized from the environment as follows [...]*

Comment: The user can still access outside if he can create symbolic links inside.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This was exactly the point of my highlight on the limitations of the shell with security. The shell is not focused on security and you can only partially manage to protect from the most obvious user errors. Hopefully there are other `fakeroot` jails and virtual hosts to limits risks of malignant actions or user errors to go beyond a defined perimeter but this is not the scope of the shell to provide such restrictions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy any sufficiently advanced user error is indistinguishable from malignant actions.